# Loan Repayment calculation in python

Tags: python

Here is what I have so far but I am just confused on how to add the following requirements Call function to compute payment with appropriate arguments, and output values for loan amount, `annual rate, number of payments, payments, amount paid back, and interest paid back`.

```
def myMonthlyPayment(Principal, annual_r, years):
    n = years * 12  # number of monthly payments
    r = (annual_r / 100) / 12  # decimal monthly interest rate from APR
    MonthlyPayment = (r * Principal * ((1+r) ** n)) / (((1+r) ** n) - 1)
    return MonthlyPayment

years = int(input('Please enter number of years of loan: '))
annual_r = float(input('Please enter the annual interest rate: '))
Principal = int(input('Please enter the amount of loan: '))

print('Monthly payment: {}'.format(myMonthlyPayment(Principal, annual_r, 
years)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Cristian Benitez
principal = float(input("total loan amount taken: "))
interest_rate = float(input("annual interest rate applied: "))
duration = int(input("loan duration in years: "))

def monthly_loan(principal,interest_rate,duration):
n = duration*12            #total number of months
r = interest_rate/(100*12) #interest per month
monthly_payment = principal*((r*((r+1)**n))/(((r+1)**n)-1)) #formula for 
compound interest applied on mothly payments.
return monthly_payment

                     #remaining loan balance calculation
def remaining_bal(principal,annual_interest_rate,duration,payments):
r = annual_interest_rate/1200 # monthly interest rate
m = r + 1
n = duration*12      #duration in months

                     # remaining balance using compound interest formula
remaining = principal*(((m**n)-(m**payments))/((m**n)-1))
return remaining

monthly = monthly_loan(principal,interest_rate,duration)

print("Loan amount: ",principal," Interest rate: ",interest_rate)
print("Duration (Years): ",duration," Monthly payment: ",int(monthly))
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `NameError: name 'm' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: It's convention to use lowercase for variable and argument names; using an uppercase 
(Principal and MyMonthlyPayment) implies that it's a class, and can
be misleading to someone reading the code.

Also it causes syntax coloring to provide incorrect information.

As for your question, you've had the user provide the annual rate, so you can print that out.

For the other values, you can either ask the user for them or calculate them as appropriate using the
same approach you've taken so far.

One tip that might be helpful is that you can pass multiple arguments to format(), like so:

```
print('Monthly payment: {}, loan amount: {}, annual rate: {}'.format(monthlyPayment, 
loan, annual_r))
```

Comment: I didn't verify the math, but your code runs and the approach is good!